# Glue in JupyterNotebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, module, markdown

A while ago I was successfully able to insert variables/strings from a code into the markdown of JupyterNotebook. I followed these steps:

```
from myst_nb import glue 

a = 5*5
glue("results", a)
```

And then I inserted the variable in the markdown section:

`My calculation of the 5x5 gave the result of {{results}}.`

Obviously the `a= 25`.

Currently, the curly brackets do not show 25 in the markdown and I don't understand why.

Could someone point me to what have changed?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems the formatting of the `glue` (and paste) library has changed : See https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/content/executable/output-insert.html for the quick introduction to its modern usage.